# How do i get individual test step results in ExtentReports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, report

I have a very silly question about Extent Reports but  i am not getting individual test steps

The logic is as below

1.`@BeforeTest`
Instantiate everything here

2.`@Test`
Passes multiple usernames and checking if those exist

3.`@AfterTest`
Teardown

4.`@AfterMethod`
flush and print the report
In the above code some usernames exist and some don't
When the extent report gets printed it just give a summary of test case and overall status
How can i know from report which user names have passed and which don't

Below is my code

```
@BeforeTest
public void instantiate()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

}


@Test(dataProvider="injectdataintovsslogin")
public void injectdataintowebsite(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException
{
    report=new ExtentReports("C:/Users/v0c1344/workspace/VSSAutomation/Reports/Report.html");
    logger=report.startTest("VSS Login");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://segotn11540.rds.volvo.com/vss_connect_testr1/Login/Login.aspx");
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Test-R1 Url is working");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='UserNameInputText']")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Brand']")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CmdLogin']")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(isuserloggedin());

    }
```

---------------Method for checking if user exists------------

```
public boolean isuserloggedin()
{
    boolean flag = false;
    if(!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty())
    {
    driver.findElement(By.id("Cancel")).click();
    }
    String title=driver.getTitle();
    if(title.contains("VSS 4.0"))
    {
        flag=true;
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "User Exists");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "User Does not Exists");
    }

return flag;
}

@AfterTest
public void teardown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

-------------Logic for Passing Users goes here-----------

```
@DataProvider(name="injectdataintovsslogin")
public Object[][] wordpressinjectprofile() throws Exception 
{

ReadExcelConfig file=new ReadExcelConfig("./Excel/TestAccount_Details_Test R11.xlsx");
int rows=file.rowcount(0);
Object[][] getdata=new Object[rows][2];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    getdata[i][0]=file.getdata(0, i, 0);
    getdata[i][1]=file.getdata(0, i, 1);

}
return getdata;

}
```

----------------Print the Report------------------

```
@AfterMethod
public void printreport()
{
report.endTest(logger);
report.flush();
} 
}
```

Attaching the screenshot for report

[Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww2TS.png)     `driver.get("C:/Users/v0c1344/workspace/VSSAutomation/Reports/Report.html");`

Comment: Any answer for this